# LTemplate and external library Armadillo

Tags: performance-tuning, librarylink, c++, compiler, compile

As a great fan of the simplicity of the LTemplate library for the end user I am now faced with a problem when apparently everything compiles correctly but the functions are not loaded from the library.

**What do I use?**

I use the (unmodified) example for integrating Armadillo into LTemplate in the repository of LTemplate by Szabolcz (to be found at [his Github repo](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate/tree/master/LTemplate/Documentation/Examples/Armadillo)). I have installed Armadillo on my computer and I link correctly against it. The compiler doesn't complain and everything works fine, if I compile (only modification of the example) as follows

```
 CompileTemplate[template,
 "IncludeDirectories" -> {"/usr/local/include"},
 "LibraryDirectories" -> {"/usr/local/lib"},
 "Libraries" -> {"armadillo"},
 $CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`ClangCompiler`ClangCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.1/bin", 
   "CompilerName" -> Automatic},
 
 (* The following options are for OS X. Adjust them for your own \
system. *)
 
 "CompileOptions" -> {"-std=c++14", "-framework Accelerate", "-O2"},
 "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print
 ]
```

**What's the mistake?**

However, if I want to load the functions, this will not work. I see for all functions of the library only the error message `The function ... was not loaded from the file ...`.

I am quite unsure how to debug this specific issue. I even looked into LTemplateInner.m itself. Unfortunately, there seems to be no `The function … was not loaded from the file…` error messages which leaves me with the assumption that something inside of `LibraryLink` does not work here.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate/issues) might be a better place for this issue.

Comment: After the failure, please check the value of ``LibraryLink`$LibraryError`` and include it in the question. Please ping me (with the `@` character) when done.

Comment: I tested this on my machine and it worked (also macOS). I use MacPorts, not Homebrew. I suspect that's related to the issue.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing out the `$LibraryError`. It was indeed connected to wrongly set paths which seem to have be set wrongly by Homebrew. Once I installed the MacPorts version of `Armadillo` everything worked just fine. Quite strange… But thanks anyway for solving this tedious issue!

Comment: Well, it *should* be possible to make it work with Homebrew ... If you have a solution, please do post an answer.